# how to remove items from a list, in a python while loop

Tags: python, list

in this code is it possible to still use a while loop but after each loop change the wordlist which is currently called wlist to the filtered variable. so if result == gr the wordlist for the next loop would be filtered 11. this will allow me to narrow down on specific words I want each loop eventually only leaving one word.

```
count = 0
while count < 5:
    count = count + 1
    result = input('''what was the result of your letter? 
please write the colour
- green = g
- yellow = y
- grey = gr
answer: ''')
    if result.lower() == 'gr':
            letter11 = input('what is the letter: ')
            filtered11 = [word for word in wlist if not any(map(lambda x: x in word, letter11))]
    if result.lower() == 'g':
            letter12 = input('what was the letter: ')
            position11 = int(input('what was the position of the letter: '))
            filtered12 = [x for x in wlist if x[position11 - 1] == letter12]
    if result.lower() == 'y':
            letter13 = input('what was the letter: ')
            position13 = int(input('what was the position of the letter : '))
            filtered13 = [word for word in wlist if letter13 in word and word[position13-1] != letter13]
```

Comment: Assign the result to `wlist` instead of `filtered11`. `wlist = [word for ...]`

Comment: And instead of `while`, use `for count in range(5):`

Comment: oh cool, its working now thanks.

Comment: @Barmar i believe `range(1, 6)` if im not mistaken

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga True. But since he never uses `count`, it may make no difference.